# C# WebClient not posting data correctly to PHP script

Tags: c#, php, post, webclient

C#:

```cs
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/api/server/key",
                                          new NameValueCollection() {
                                              { "key", key }
                                          });

    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

PHP:

```php
$key = $_POST["key"];
echo($key);
```

When this runs, the PHP $_POST array never has any value actually posted to it. Meaning that the echo line has no output.

Also, yes, 'key' does have a value, it is just cropped out in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, the expression `new NameValueCollection() { ... }` does what you think it should do.

You should be explicit and say

```
NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add("key", key);
byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/api/server/key",
                                      values);
```

---

Searching for object initializers reveals [Collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#Anchor_2)

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method.

And an example

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sylvester", Age=8 },
    new Cat(){ Name = "Whiskers", Age=2 },
    new Cat(){ Name = "Sasha", Age=14 }
};
```

So maybe using the initializer without the parentheses works, e.g.

```
byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/api/server/key",
                                      new NameValueCollection {
                                          { "key", key }
                                      });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same either way? Nonetheless, it still doesn't fix my issue of PHP not getting the POST data.

Comment: If this doesn't work either, then I would guess the URL is wrong.

Comment: Sigh... I feel like an idiot. I seriously thought I was losing my mind over this. I forgot the / after key in the url causing it to not post to the index.php in that directory. Thank you all for the help. I'm going to go cry now :)

Answer (score 0):

url encode the value like:

```
client.UploadValues("http://example.com/api/server/key", new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "key", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this actually doesn't work. Still doesn't post the value.

Comment: here is the whole function if it changes anything, although I can't see how it would. https://codetidy.com/9486/

Comment: what is the value of the key you post? may be it is an empty string?

Comment: No, it is a 64 character long string.

Comment: I also tried it with WebRequest and had the exact same issue. I know the web server is configured correctly, so it has to be C#. Ex: https://codetidy.com/9488/